# Retweet using Twitter4j Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

i'm trying make simple app twitter and i use twitter4j library and i got good tutorial how to login and post twitter used that library. my app display timeline and had retweet button, my question how to retweet using twitter4j library?

Comment: Can you share your code of re-tweeting with me, including login and getting timeline? I stuck in re-tweeting. Please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call [`Status#retweet()`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/StatusMethods.html#retweetStatus%28long%29) or [`TwitterStream#retweet()`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/StatusMethods.html#retweetStatus%28long%29) with the original tweet id.

You can also use `Twitter#retweetStatus()`, for example:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.retweetStatus(idOfStatusToRetweet);
```

Comment: Can you share your code of re-tweeting with me, including login and getting timeline? I stuck in re-tweeting. Please help..

Comment: Not working.. there is no method like retweetStatus()